# Importing multiple KML files to ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, kml

I have a number of KML files and I would like to convert them to Shapefile format.

Is it possible to build a model that iterates over a number of KML files?

I tried to use File iterator, but it doesn't seem to work.

[image: KMLs to layer]

Comment: Since KML files may contain various geometry types and shape files can only accommodate one, this tool specifically asks you a "Geodatabase" location where to save (possible) geometries. If you change the name of "Output Geodatabase" to "%Name%" (as in your iterators output parameter), you will be able to extract them in a geodatabase as one or more Feature Classes not as a shapefile. However by using Calculate Value tool and with a bit of Python code, this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

As [commented by @KHibma](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150115/importing-multiple-kml-files-to-arcgis#comment219952_150115):

> Might be quicker to copy/paste the 2nd copy sample from `[`[the KML
>   Layer (Conversion) documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000004w000000)`]`which does exactly what you
>   want (well it consolidates all KML into a single fGDB and maybe you
>   dont want that part - so you could remove it)